Appending a single row of a DataFrame to another DataFrame using pd.concat()
I have DataFrames: df1, and df2 and this code:
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    try:
        #check whether 'DATE' in df is valid
        datetime.strptime(df1.loc[i,'DATE'], '%d.%m.%Y')
    except ValueError:
        # SHOULD copy the row in Question into df2
        df2 = pd.concat([df2,df.loc[i]], ignore_index=True)
        
        #df2 = df2._append(df1.loc[i], ignore_index=True)

Now, pd._append() works, but I cannot get pd.concat() to work for some reason.
It creates a completely new column in df2 and copies every value of the row from df1 separately into it.
Where did I go wrong?

You should never add rows 1 by 1, collect in a list and concat in the end.
